# How to switch between different view by changing the content in <div> tag

Tags: html, laravel-5, datatables

I have different view (grid and list). I am using datatable as list view but the datatable function is not working. I am using ajax to refresh the content in div tag.

```
    $('#grid').click(function(){
        $('#searchBar').show();
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'/refreshList',
            dataType: 'HTML',
            success:function(html){
                $('#body').html(html);
            },
            error:function(){
            }
        });
    });

In my another list view file

    <table class="table display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="main-table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
       <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
   <td></td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#main-table').DataTable({
                "responsive": true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I will refresh the content of div replace by this table, but it shows without datatable function. ps.written in 2 different file.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: i had updated with some of the code.